# Drag and Drop columns with react-sortable-hoc

Tags: html-table, components, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm looking for an example of drag & drop columns with react-sortable-hoc and react-virtualized, I have not figured out how I can do it. 
Is there anyone who has a solution?

```
<Table
                                        height={height}
                                        width={1500}
                                        headerHeight={styles.rowHeight}
                                        rowHeight={styles.rowHeight}
                                        rowCount={tableData.length}
                                        rowGetter={getRow}
                                        headerStyle={styles.headerRow}
                                        rowStyle={getRowStyle}
                                        headerClassName="headerColumn"
                                    >
                                        {
                                            columns.map((line, key) => (
                                                <Column
                                                    key={key}
                                                    width={line.width}
                                                    dataKey={line.dataKey}
                                                    label={line.label}
                                                />
                                            ))
                                        }
                                    </Table>
```

I succeeded for the rows but not for columns by following this link: https://embed.plnkr.co/N4iYHYE9gPLp4Y3NHbhk/

Comment: Do you want to  add the bottom index of the next container , I have succeeded to add that to bottom but  without animations